# How to show password as watermark in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anyone please tell me watermark password textbox in windows phone 7.
i didn't find any samples on that.
please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Watermark TextBox control available on Codeplex.com :-

http://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/

The following article may also be useful :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WatermarkedTextBox-custom-control